# Ruby- Beginner ran into unknown syntax

Tags: ruby

Trying to learn Ruby I ran into this kind of syntax.... Can anyone explain me what it means?

```
a = nil if b.nonzero?
```

> nonzero? : Returns self if num is not zero, nil otherwise.

And thus does not return a boolean

Comment: `nil` is falsy value, so if `b` is nonzero, the `if` condition will evaluate to equivalent to `false`.  `Returns self` means the value of `b` will be returned if its non-zero

Comment: You can use non-boolean values in conditions in Ruby.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *specific* part of the syntax are you talking about that is unknown to you? There are 5 different syntax elements in the code you posted: an assignment to a local variable, the literal `nil`, the modifier conditional `if`, a local variable dereference and a method call. Which one is unknown to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in ruby are truthy and falsey. That is, if a value is not nil, or false, it is true. So if you have a function that returns `1`, you can use that in a boolean expression `some_function && true` would resolve true.

Likewise, if it returned `nil`, `some_function && true` would return false.

There's a detailed and in depth explanation here: https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362